# Use lapply to put dataframes into list and keep dataframe names

Tags: r, twitter, lapply

I'm using TwitteR to loop over a list of twitter handles and create multiple dataframes using the following code.

```
for(user in twitter_handles$`Official Twitter`){
    twitter=userTimeline(user,n=100,includeRts=TRUE)
    assign(paste0("df.",user),twListToDF(twitter))
}
```

This creates 100 data frames with tweets and accompanying info for each twitter handle. This creates a very cluttered global environmentd so I then use lapply() to put the data frames into a list  and then drop them with rm() as follows:

```
twitter_data <- lapply(ls(pattern="df"), function(x) get(x))
rm(list = ls(pattern="df"))
```

But the dataframes in this list lose their names. Is there a way that I can keep the names of the dataframes when using lapply to put them into the list and then loop over the dataframes to perform the following transformations?

```
for(df in twitter_data){
    df$created <- format(df$created, tz="America/New_York",usetz=TRUE)
    df$day_created <-format(as.Date(df$created, format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
    df$day_created <- as.Date(df$day_created)
}
```

Comment: Maybe `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` instead of `lapply` will help?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem! Glad it works